# python copying directory and reading text files Remotely

Tags: python, windows, file, wmi, remote-access

I'm about to start working on a project where a Python script is able to remote into a Windows Server and read a bunch of text files in a certain directory. I was planning on using a module called `WMI` as that is the only way I have been able to successfully remotely access a windows server using Python, But upon further research I'm not sure i am going to be using this module.

The only problem is that, these text files are constantly updating about every 2 seconds and I'm afraid that the script will crash if it comes into an `MutEx` error where it tries to open the file while it is being rewritten. The only thing I can think of is creating a new directory, copying all the files (via script) into this directory in the state that they are in and reading them from there; and just constantly overwriting these ones with the new ones once it finishes checking all of the old ones. Unfortunately I don't know how to execute this correctly, or efficiently.

How can I go about doing this? Which python module would be best for this execution?

Answer (score 0):

I've done some work with WMI before (though not from Python) and I would not try to use it for a project like this. As you said WMI tends to be obscure and my experience says such things are hard to support long-term.

I would either work at the Windows API level, or possibly design a service that performs the desired actions access this service as needed. Of course, you will need to install this service on each machine you need to control. Both approaches have merit. The WinAPI approach pretty much guarantees you don't invent any new security holes and is simpler initially. The service approach should make the application faster and required less network traffic. I am sure you can think of others easily.

You still have to have the necessary permissions, network ports, etc. regardless of the approach. E.g., WMI is usually blocked by firewalls and you still run as some NT process.

Sorry, not really an answer as such -- meant as a long comment.

ADDED

Re: API programming, though you have no Windows API experience, I expect you find it familiar for tasks such as you describe, i.e., reading and writing files, scanning directories are nothing unique to Windows. You only need to learn about the parts of the API that interest you.

Once you create the appropriate security contexts and start your client process, there is nothing service-oriented in the, i.e., your can simply open and close files, etc., ignoring that fact that the files are remote, other than server name being included in the UNC name of the file/folder location.

Comment: I agree, after looking at WMI im not sure I want to go about using this module. Although i have zero experienc with any sort of API

Answer (score 0):

There is Windows support in Ansible these days. It uses winrm. There are plenty of Python libraries that utilize winrm, just google it, but Ansible is very versatile.

http://docs.ansible.com/intro_windows.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: From the looks of it, It needs a Linux control machine, where in my case I have a Windows control machine

Comment: Yes I forgot about that :/ you do need a Linux control machine. However, if it meets your reqs, you can use a Linux vm. I have a setup like this and it works quite well, albiet it's not in a production environment. Also, I haven't tried it before, but you could probably use cygwin and setup an SSH server simulate a Linux box